# LOAD DATA INFILE not working using \Zend\Db\Adapter

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

The below code works with directly with PHP's PDO but if I use Zend\Db\Adapter it is throwing an error. The first try block does not work while the second one works fine and all data gets imported.

```
try {
    $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $result = $dbAdapter->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '?' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '" . '"' . "' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES",
                    array('/tmp/feed.csv'));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error1!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myapps_test', 'myapps_test_user', 'pwd');
    $result = $dbh->exec("LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/feed.csv' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '" . '"' . "' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES");
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error2!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

The error I get for the first try block:

```
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException: Statement could not be executed

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 13 Can't get stat of '/db/dev/mysqldata/myapps_test/?' (Errcode: 2)
```

The location /db/dev/mysqldata/myapps_test is where the mysql server's database files are located.

Comment: That looks like a permissions problem. Typically the problem occurs with the import file, not with the table files. You might want to read this: http://thinkinglemur.com/index.php/2009/06/load-data-infile-and-file-permissions-on-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'?'` should be just `?` in the first query (the single quotes are added automatically). I think this is what's giving you path problems.